# Why is a function being self-invoked within an object literal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

### jQuery (fragmented for simplicity)

The *interval* property contains an setInterval() function with in the object literal *slider*, the setInterval() defined in interval is invoking itself, or at-least appears to be, but why?

```
 var slider = {
    config : function(imgs, callback){
        //mandatory
        var images = $(imgs);

        //optional
        var animationInterval;
        var animationTime;

        callback(images);            
    },
    target : 0,
    get lastElem(){
        return this.images.length-1;
    },
    interval : setInterval(function () {
       setSlider();
    }, 3000)
};

slider.config('ul.images li', setConfig);
slider.images.hide().first().show();

function setConfig(imgs){
   slider.images = imgs;
}

function setSlider(dest) { 
    slider.target === slider.lastElem ? slider.target = 0 : slider.target++;        
    slider.images.hide().eq(slider.target).fadeIn(1000);
    slider.triggers.removeClass('active').eq(slider.target).addClass('active');
}
```

<kbd>**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3fCw5/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: Are you asking why `setInterval` is invoked when the _Object_ is defined?

Comment: yes, i figured i'd have to call it -> `slider.interval()`

Comment: Try `setInterval.bind(window, function () {
       setSlider();
    }, 3000)`

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon, that didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Weird, it work here : http://jsfiddle.net/8BRCy/ (uncomment the line to launch it)...

Comment: this is weird. why are all the comments and answers trying to *fix* something? the asker is just asking why the code does it this way.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon, yeah, that's weird, i was getting illegal invocation flags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current code you are assigning the RESULT of `setInterval()` to the interval property. What I would suggest is to wrap the `setInterval()` call in a function, like this:

```
interval : function() {
        setInterval(function() {
            setSlider();
        }, 3000);
}
```

Then, you should be able to call `slider.interval()`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and solution. I just checked what `console.log(slider.interval)` was previously returning, it was returning `1`, any clue of its relevance?

Comment: setInterval returns a reference, so if you wanted to stop the function from running later, you can call clearInterval(); for example: `var myInt = setInterval(myfunc(),2000); clearInterval(myInt);`

Answer (score 4):

When you make an object literal, the values you type in are evaluated as expressions.

```
function square(x) {
  return x * x;
}

var lookup = {
  'two': square(2)
};

console.log(lookup['two']); // 4
```

Here, you're calling `setInterval` instead of `square`. `setInterval` takes a function and period and schedules that function to run repeatedly. It returns a numeric identifier of the scheduling, so that you can stop it later with `clearInterval`. For example, you could later do `clearInterval(slider.interval);` to stop setSlider from being called.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, "values you type in are evaluated as expressions" was particularly helpful.